# AWS Webapi with API Gateway and lambda function published but not showing in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I am using Visual Studio 2019. Created a very basic Serverless .Net Core 2.1 Web API with AWS Lambda. When i published it by right clicking on web api project -> Publish it to AWS Lambda it seems published since the status within Visual studio says "CREATE_COMPLETE", but when i click on the generated URL, it says 
{"message": "Internal server error"}

Then logged into my AWS console, verified that the s3 bucket that i mentioned during the published process is created there and it does have my project files there, but i dont see any lambda functions created.

I cannot figure out how to fix this, and why the VS Studion says Created Complete and does not show any error but actually its not working

Comment: Do you see anything created in cloudformation?

Comment: Any chance you created it one region, but you are looking in a different one?